# Why do Samsung S1 and S2 allocating different heap size of memory for the same APP

Tags: android, heap-memory, loadimage

I'm developing an Android Game application that requires loading a lot of images(png).
I used BitmapFactory.decodeStream to load the images:

```
BitmapFactory.Options opt = new BitmapFactory.Options(); 
opt.inScaled = false; 
opt.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;     
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(context.getResources().openRawResource(context.getRes‌​ources().getIdentifier(filenames.get(i),"drawable",context.getPackageName())),nul‌​l,opt);
```

It works fine on Samsung S1 i9000(Android 2.3.3).
But when I test it on Samsung S2 i9100(Android 4.1.2) it crashes when I load the images.

I launched DDMS to check the heap and found out something weird.
It seems S1 only allocated 5.494mb for my application, when S2 allocated over 43.280mb!

I would really appreciate if someone could tell me why there's such big difference between these two phones.

Screenshot [image](https://www.dropbox.com/s/9htd0b0min14ox6/log.png)

Comment: Screen densities are different. I assume you provide different images for different resolutions, aren't you? Are your PNGs optimised for all resolutions?

Comment: thank you David,But I didn't provide different images for different resolutions.I only provide one resolution images.

Comment: Do you use `dp` or `dip` to specify image sizes? If `dp`, try providing upscaled images to S2

Comment: No. I just want to load image. But it's fine in S1 , crash in S2.
I want to know what difference between these two phones.

Comment: They are too many to list: screen density, OS version, CPU. You should post the piece of code in question, maybe it;s not phones fault.

Comment: BitmapFactory.Options opt = new BitmapFactory.Options();
opt.inScaled = false;
opt.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;    
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(context.getResources().openRawResource(context.getResources().getIdentifier(filenames.get(i),"drawable",context.getPackageName())),null,opt); 
I am using surfaceview to show my animations.
Before I start my animations, I will pre load animation images
S1 can load all my images,but S2 will crash(heap overflow).
Look my screenshot image, we can see when i load images,s1 and s2 heap usage is difference.(S1:5.494MB,S2:43.28MB